# Manga where the main character is kicked out of a country and the "spirits" leave too

Tags: story-identification, manga

1. The main character is kicked out of a country for a reason I can't really remember.
2. The main character has no choice but to go to another country.
3. Meanwhile, the Spirits, that have been providing blessing and skills to the country's residents, got angry and all of them followed our mc after some discussion among themselves.. Meanwhile, what happened is chaos as the country's people struggles with their power disappearing, along with Magic. Basically they are in big trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Phantasm Trainer (Yuiitsu Muni no Saikyou Tamer)*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5neupvy/yuiitsu-Muni-No-Saikyou-Tamer).

> It's difficult to be a phantasm tamer when no one believes in invisible followers, not to mention tamers already being quite unpopular.
>
> Follow our hero's journey to be recognized!
>
> [image]

Note that the phantasms he trains are in fact local spirits and that when he leaves the country, people's magic stops working.