# Manga where MC is weak but the sprits/fairies follow him

Tags: story-identification, manga

I know that in the start the MC wants to apply to some sort of job but is declined as he was weak and when he tells his companion (she is also a spirit or a spirit whisper) that lets leave the country. She tells all the spirits of that country to leave the country and move with him. After some debate, they all agree to move out of the country, which resulted in many powerful people (hero, saintess, etc) to lose their power and the king is dumbstruck on the news as well.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [Manga where the main character is kicked out of a country and the "spirits" leave too](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276344/manga-where-the-main-character-is-kicked-out-of-a-country-and-the-spirits-leav) - *Phantasm Trainer (Yuiitsu Muni no Saikyou Tamer).*

Comment: yes this was the one thanks @Valorum

Comment: [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)